# How to unit test a ViewModel that extends AndroidViewModel. Having issues with the application in the constructor

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mvvm, viewmodel

So I'm having to write unit tests and I need to test my ViewModels.

I have a base ViewModel and that BaseViewModel extends AndroidViewModel. The reason I extend AndroidViewModel is so that I can use the context for Dagger.

My BaseViewModel.

```
public class BaseViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

protected @Inject SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper;

public BaseViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);

    //Only inject sharedPreferences since it is used in almost all of the VMs.
    ((CommissioningApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

}

Essentially I'm having issues creating an instance of my ViewModel in my unit tests. I have tried many things and have been unsuccessful.

I have considered extending ViewModel instead of AndroidViewModel and creating a Factory that will pass the application context to my ViewModels. But in the end I will run towards the same issue whenever I try to create an instance of my ViewModel.

Does anyone have an example that I could follow on how to test this? Or would have I have to do Instrumented testing instead of Unit testing?

I'm very new to testing so maybe I'm not doing things properly, any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why use field injection not constructor injection? I think constructor injection is more suitable for this case.

Comment: @SandyLin I ended up creating a ViewModelFactory that is is injected in my activitiy/fragment. That factory then takes care of giving the viewmodel the things it needs. In the end i also ended up going away from the AndoridViewModel and switched to the ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599337/how-to-mock-application-class-to-unit-test-viewmodel):

```
Mockito.mock(Application::class.java)
```