# How to mock Application class to unit test ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-architecture-components

I have a `View Model` that extends `AndroidViewModel`

```
class MoveViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application),CoroutineScope{
    ....
}
```

And I want to unit test it but I cannot figure out how to Mock the Application class

```
@Test
    fun testSearchDataValidation() {
        val application = Mockito.mock(Application::class.java)
        val viewModel = MoveViewModel(application)

        .....
    }
```

But when I go to run the test I get an error that `Mockito` cannot mock `Application`

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Mockito cannot mock this
>   class: class android.app.Application.
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.

How do I mock the Application class to pass it to my view model?

**Edit:**

Here is my folder hierarchy  as suggested by @farhanjk

[image]

Comment: You're trying to mock the Application class in an AndroidTest, that doesn't make much sense since you can get the actual Application instance

Comment: @lelloman not sure what you mean, I thought that the androidTest was for when you need to work with the android framework, the ViewModel uses some shared preferences. I am very new to unit testing in android so I dont understand everything fully but can I do these tests in the `test` folder?

Comment: If you are really unit testing a view model you should be able to do so in `test` folder, you would need to mock all Android dependencies (like `Application` or `SharedPreferences`), tests in `androidTest` folder instead have your actual application available. You should be able to unit test view models in `test`, they're much faster than `androidTest`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Mockito.mock(Application::class.java)`

In your `test` folder, create a hierarchy like following:

[image]

In the `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file, just put a one-liner text `mock-maker-inline`.

[Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable)

Comment: I had to update my mockito version and it started working