# How to test ViewModel when extended by AndroidViewModel

Tags: android-studio, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I am testing the ViewModel which is extended by `AndroidViewModel(application)`.

Below is my `ViewModel`

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MoviesRepository,
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var movieData: MutableLiveData<List<Data>> = MutableLiveData()
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData(false)
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String?>(null)

    init {
        getData()
    }

    private fun getData() {
        if (checkInternetConnection()) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
                isLoading.postValue(true)
                kotlin.runCatching {
                    repository.getMoviesData().sortedBy { it.title }
                }.onSuccess {
                    movieData.postValue(it)
                    isLoading.postValue(false)
                }.onFailure {
                    errorMessage.postValue(it.message)
                    isLoading.postValue(false)
                }
                isLoading.postValue(false)
            }
        } else {
            errorMessage.postValue("Internet not available")
        }
    }

    suspend fun filterMovies(searchTerm: String) {
        movieData.value = repository.getMoviesData().filter { mvData ->
            mvData.genre.contains(searchTerm, ignoreCase = true) ||
                    mvData.title.contains(searchTerm, ignoreCase = true)
        }
    }

    private fun checkInternetConnection(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            getApplication<Application>().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork = connectivityManager.activeNetwork ?: return false
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork) ?: return false
        return when {
            capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) -> true
            capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> true
            capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET) -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want this application class to be mocked in the test to initialize the viewmodel to write the test case.

Below is my test which I have written :

```
class HomeFragmentViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    private val repository: MoviesRepository = mockk{
        coEvery { getMoviesData() } returns movieList
    }

    private val observer: Observer<List<Data>> = mockk(relaxed = true)

    private lateinit var viewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel

    val context: Context = mock(Context::class.java)

    val application: Application = mock(Application::class.java)

    private val movieList = listOf(
        Data(
            id = 0,
            year = "1984",
            title = "Coming to America",
            genre = "Comedy",
            poster = ""
        ),
        Data(
            id = 1,
            year = "2022",
            title = "Coming 2 America",
            genre = "Comedy",
            poster = ""
        ),
        Data(
            id = 2,
            year = "2020",
            title = "Lucky",
            genre = "Action",
            poster = ""
        )
    )

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        viewModel = HomeFragmentViewModel(repository, application = application)
        viewModel.movieData.observeForever(observer)

    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        viewModel.movieData.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    @Test
    fun `filter movies by genre should return matching genres`() = runBlocking {
        val expectedList = listOf(
            Data(
                id = 0,
                year = "1984",
                title = "Coming to America",
                genre = "Comedy",
                poster = ""
            ),
            Data(
                id = 1,
                year = "2022",
                title = "Coming 2 America",
                genre = "Comedy",
                poster = ""
            )
        )
        viewModel.filterMovies("Comedy")
        verify { observer.onChanged(expectedList) }
        assertEquals(expectedList, viewModel.movieData.value)
    }
}
```

Now while running the test I am getting below error :

```
class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class android.net.ConnectivityManager (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; android.net.ConnectivityManager is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class android.net.ConnectivityManager (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; android.net.ConnectivityManager is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.harry.moviesapp.viewModel.HomeFragmentViewModel.checkInternetConnection(HomeFragmentViewModel.kt:62)
    at com.harry.moviesapp.viewModel.HomeFragmentViewModel.getData(HomeFragmentViewModel.kt:34)
    at com.harry.moviesapp.viewModel.HomeFragmentViewModel.<init>(HomeFragmentViewModel.kt:30)
    at com.harry.moviesapp.viewModel.HomeFragmentViewModelTest.setUp(HomeFragmentViewModelTest.kt:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:61)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

I have checked similar links such as [How to mock Application class to unit test ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599337/how-to-mock-application-class-to-unit-test-viewmodel)

But my code is not working. Is there any way to initialize the application class using Mockito?

Answer (score 0):

the first is check the use mockk instead mock for the generate the test doubles.

But the problem per se is that not provides a mock to the ConnectivityManager:

```
every { 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) 
} returns yourMock
```

The above is complicated (Everything related to mock of the context is complex)

Maybe your can move the internet validation to another class and generate a static access to the utility, with this also isn't necessary to use AndroidViewModel.